# Hackers tried user name with wrong case

Tags: users

Today, WordFence sent an email that someone tried to log into a client site with a user name that was totally correct, except for the case. It occurred to me that maybe the only system that isn't case sensitive in the login process is their Windows network.

While I recommended that they get a secure certificate for all of their domain names so that the data is encrypted, is there another common hole in the login data flow that would pick up a username without the case? For example, I believe that the WordPress login form would have to pick up the username with the case, as entered. And, a keyboard tracker would pick up that the shift key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress do not consider user names to be private information. It is trivial to get a user name of any one which has authored a post, and it is not very complex to get a list of active user names based on the errors displayed at the login form when using a wrong password.

Regardless of my personal dislike to this policy, in the end most user names can be easily guessed and more targeted attacks can use email adrress, which for many is a public information, to attempt login.

Best advice is probably to put less emphasize on "security" plugins which report many things you either can do nothing about, or are just part of the "the internet is full of evil people" fact, and focus on keeping good user passwords and limit user capabilities as much as possible.